How to verify if a request is called from a specific Android app in Spring Boot
I've developed a server application using Spring Boot and an Android client app. The server provides several APIs for the Android application.
I need to verify on the server side if requests are called from my Android application when handling the requests. I want to handle only the requests called from the Android application that I deployed and I should block API calls made via commands like curl.
Since secret values can be identified through APK reverse engineering, I cannot use methods that include related API keys or encryption keys within the Android application.
Is this possible?
If yes, what method should be used?

Identifying a specific user
You can pass headers from your application to your server to identify which user is sending the request. Additionally you can also log the Android version, the app version, and whatever data is needed.
As you said, your app can be reverse engineered to know this secret header, right. Read the below point for this
Handling VPNs, or custom IP requests.
You can use SSL Pinning to prevent anyone from intercepting your requests "easily"
SSL (Secure socket layer) Certificate Pinning, or pinning for short, is the process of associating a host with its certificate or public key. Once you know a host’s certificate or public key, you pin it to that host.
In other words, you configure the app to reject all but one or a few predefined certificates or public keys. Whenever the app connects to a server, it compares the server certificate with the pinned certificate(s) or public key(s). If and only if they match, the app trusts the server and establishes the connection
You can read about how to do that in Android here
Additionally, you can implement checks to prevent installation of your app on the device if it has some malicious apps/sniffing tools installed like HTTPCanary for example
Preventing reverse engineering of your app

You can use Google's SafetyNet/ Play Integrity APIs to detect if your app is downloaded from a legitimate source and is/or legitimate ( not tampered with). Usually when your app is reverse engineered, and tampered, the signing certificate changes. You can detect that easily, using these APIs

You can use obfuscation tools like Proguard, or maybe some paid tools, to obfuscate your code. Obfuscation makes it harder to read and understand the code once your app is reverse engineered.


Also please note that listed above are just some ways to PREVENT Reverse Engineering or Hacking and it can't be avoided completely, because a persistent person will break it anyway.
Hope this helps..
